# Setting aspect ratio of 3D plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplot3d

I am trying to plot a 3D image of the seafloor from the data of a sonar run over a 500m by 40m portion of the seafloor. I am using matplotlib/mplot3d with Axes3D and I want to be able to change the aspect ratio of the axes so that the x & y axis are to scale. An example script with generated data rather than the real data is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

# Create figure.
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection = '3d')

# Generate example data.
R, Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0, 500, 0.5), np.arange(0, 40, 0.5))
z = 0.1 * np.abs(np.sin(R/40) * np.sin(Y/6))

# Plot the data.
surf = ax.plot_surface(R, Y, z, cmap=cm.jet, linewidth=0)
fig.colorbar(surf)

# Set viewpoint.
ax.azim = -160
ax.elev = 30

# Label axes.
ax.set_xlabel('Along track (m)')
ax.set_ylabel('Range (m)')
ax.set_zlabel('Height (m)')

# Save image.
fig.savefig('data.png')
```

And the output image from this script:

[image: matplotlib output image]

Now I would like to change it so that 1 metre in the along-track (x) axis is the same as 1 metre in the range (y) axis (or maybe a different ratio depending on the relative sizes involved). I would also like to set the ratio of the z-axis, again not neccessarily to 1:1 due to the relative sizes in the data, but so the axis is smaller than the current plot.

I have tried building and using [this branch of matplotlib](https://github.com/WeatherGod/matplotlib/tree/mplot3d/pbaspect), following the example script in [this message from the mailing list](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.matplotlib.general/27415), but adding the `ax.pbaspect = [1.0, 1.0, 0.25]` line to my script (having uninstalled the 'standard' version of matplotlib to ensure the custom version was being used) didn't make any difference in the generated image.

**Edit:** So the desired output would be something like the following (crudely edited with Inkscape) image. In this case I haven't set a 1:1 ratio on the x/y axes because that looks ridiculously thin, but I have spread it out so it isn't square as on the original output.

[image: Desired output]

Comment: See [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30223161/matplotlib-mplot3d-how-to-increase-the-size-of-an-axis-stretch-in-a-3d-plo) for a solution.

Comment: As of matplotlib 3.3.0, it is recommended to `set_box_aspect()`. See the [newer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64487277/8696224) answers [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63625222/8696224).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Add following code before savefig:

```
ax.auto_scale_xyz([0, 500], [0, 500], [0, 0.15])
```

[image]

If you want no square axis:

edit the `get_proj` function inside site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\axes3d.py:

```
xmin, xmax = np.divide(self.get_xlim3d(), self.pbaspect[0])
ymin, ymax = np.divide(self.get_ylim3d(), self.pbaspect[1])
zmin, zmax = np.divide(self.get_zlim3d(), self.pbaspect[2])
```

then add one line to set pbaspect:

```
ax = fig.gca(projection = '3d')
ax.pbaspect = [2.0, 0.6, 0.25]
```

[image]

Comment: Hmmm. That does get the scaling of the axes correct, but results in a lot of wasted space. While I *could* save this as SVG and edit it manually (like what I did with the desired image I just updated the question with) this would get very tedious when I have a large number of images to create, and I'm not sure it could be automated...

Comment: You can use the pbaspect modification to get no square axes. I have edited the answer.

Comment: I think this is a very useful hack. Note that it is within the `get_proj` function where one has to modify this value. Also note that after modifying it the way shown here, you must give a `pbaspect` value. One can avoid this by adding something like `try:
            self.localPbAspect=self.pbaspect
        except AttributeError:
            self.localPbAspect=[1,1,1]` and divide by `self.localPbAspect[...]`, or something like this...as you might not always want to set a `pbaspect` manually.

Answer (score 2):

An issue has been opened over at github: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8593

The above solutions don't seem to work any more. One has to edit the `get_proj` function inside `site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\axes3d.py` in the following way now:

```
        try:
            self.localPbAspect = self.pbaspect
        except AttributeError:
            self.localPbAspect = [1,1,1]

        xmin, xmax = ( lim / self.localPbAspect[0] for lim in self.get_xlim3d() )
        ymin, ymax = ( lim / self.localPbAspect[1] for lim in self.get_ylim3d() )
        zmin, zmax = ( lim / self.localPbAspect[2] for lim in self.get_zlim3d() )
```

Answer (score 0):

That how i solved the wasted space problem:

```
try: 
    self.localPbAspect=self.pbaspect
    zoom_out = (self.localPbAspect[0]+self.localPbAspect[1]+self.localPbAspect[2]) 
except AttributeError: 
    self.localPbAspect=[1,1,1]
    zoom_out = 0 
xmin, xmax = self.get_xlim3d() /  self.localPbAspect[0]
ymin, ymax = self.get_ylim3d() /  self.localPbAspect[1]
zmin, zmax = self.get_zlim3d() /  self.localPbAspect[2]

# transform to uniform world coordinates 0-1.0,0-1.0,0-1.0
worldM = proj3d.world_transformation(xmin, xmax,
                                         ymin, ymax,
                                         zmin, zmax)

# look into the middle of the new coordinates
R = np.array([0.5*self.localPbAspect[0], 0.5*self.localPbAspect[1], 0.5*self.localPbAspect[2]])
xp = R[0] + np.cos(razim) * np.cos(relev) * (self.dist+zoom_out)
yp = R[1] + np.sin(razim) * np.cos(relev) * (self.dist+zoom_out)
zp = R[2] + np.sin(relev) * (self.dist+zoom_out)
E = np.array((xp, yp, zp))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to declare here full solution for now.
[Axes3D.set_box_aspect](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.set_box_aspect)

```
ax.set_box_aspect(aspect=(x_scale, y_scale, z_scale))
```

### Full code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np

# Create figure.
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 9))
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

# Generate example data.
R, Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0, 500, 0.5), np.arange(0, 40, 0.5))
z = 0.1 * np.abs(np.sin(R/40) * np.sin(Y/6))

# Plot the data.
surf = ax.plot_surface(R, Y, z, cmap=cm.jet, linewidth=0)
fig.colorbar(surf)

# Set viewpoint.
ax.azim = -160
ax.elev = 30

# Label axes.
ax.set_xlabel('Along track (m)')
ax.set_ylabel('Range (m)')
ax.set_zlabel('Height (m)')

# padding for axis label not to overlap with axis ticks
ax.xaxis.labelpad=30    

# changing aspect ratio
ax.set_box_aspect(aspect=(4, 1, 0.5), zoom=1.3)

# Save image.
fig.savefig('data.jpg', dpi=200)
```

[Resulting plot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOIwE.jpg)

Thanks to @ImportanceOfBeingErnest for referring to question with answer.