# How to set the 'equal' aspect ratio for all axes (x, y, z)

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis, aspect-ratio, matplotlib-3d

When I set up an equal aspect ratio for a 3d graph, the `z-axis` does not change to 'equal'. So this:

```py
fig = pylab.figure()
mesFig = fig.gca(projection='3d', adjustable='box')
mesFig.axis('equal')
mesFig.plot(xC, yC, zC, 'r.')
mesFig.plot(xO, yO, zO, 'b.')
pyplot.show()
```

Gives me the following:

[image: img1]

Where obviously the unit length of z-axis is not equal to x- and y- units.

How can I make the unit length of all three axes equal? All the solutions I found did not work.

Comment: As of matplotlib 3.3.0, it is recommended to `set_box_aspect()`. See the [newer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64487277/8696224) answers [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63625222/8696224).

Comment: With a single (functional) line edit I just repaired the [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31364297/2525140) to use `set_box_aspect` so that it works with matplotlib 3.3.0 and later.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

I believe matplotlib does not yet set correctly equal axis in 3D... But I found a trick some times ago (I don't remember where) that I've adapted using it. The concept is to create a fake cubic bounding box around your data.
You can test it with the following code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.set_aspect('equal')

X = np.random.rand(100)*10+5
Y = np.random.rand(100)*5+2.5
Z = np.random.rand(100)*50+25

scat = ax.scatter(X, Y, Z)

# Create cubic bounding box to simulate equal aspect ratio
max_range = np.array([X.max()-X.min(), Y.max()-Y.min(), Z.max()-Z.min()]).max()
Xb = 0.5*max_range*np.mgrid[-1:2:2,-1:2:2,-1:2:2][0].flatten() + 0.5*(X.max()+X.min())
Yb = 0.5*max_range*np.mgrid[-1:2:2,-1:2:2,-1:2:2][1].flatten() + 0.5*(Y.max()+Y.min())
Zb = 0.5*max_range*np.mgrid[-1:2:2,-1:2:2,-1:2:2][2].flatten() + 0.5*(Z.max()+Z.min())
# Comment or uncomment following both lines to test the fake bounding box:
for xb, yb, zb in zip(Xb, Yb, Zb):
   ax.plot([xb], [yb], [zb], 'w')

plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

z data are about an order of magnitude larger than x and y, but even with equal axis option, matplotlib autoscale z axis:

[image: bad]

But if you add the bounding box, you obtain a correct scaling:

[image]

Comment: In this case you do not even need the `equal` statement - it will be always equal.

Comment: This works fine if you are plotting only one set of data but what about when there are more data sets all on the same 3d plot?  In question, there were 2 data sets so it's a simple thing to combine them but that could get unreasonable quickly if plotting several different data sets.

Comment: @stvn66, I was plotting up to five data sets in one graph with this solutions and it worked fine for me.

Comment: This works perfectly. For those who want this in function form, which takes an axis object and performs the operations above, I encourage them to check out @karlo answer below. It is a slightly cleaner solution.

Comment: @user1329187 -- I found this did not work for me without the `equal` statement.

Comment: After I updated anaconda, ax.set_aspect("equal") reported error:
NotImplementedError: It is not currently possible to manually set the aspect on 3D axes

Answer (score 87):

I like some of the previously posted solutions, but they do have the drawback that you need to keep track of the ranges and means over all your data. This could be cumbersome if you have multiple data sets that will be plotted together. To fix this, I made use of the `ax.get_[xyz]lim3d()` methods and put the whole thing into a standalone function that can be called just once before you call `plt.show()`. Here is the new version:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def set_axes_equal(ax):
    """
    Make axes of 3D plot have equal scale so that spheres appear as spheres,
    cubes as cubes, etc.

    Input
      ax: a matplotlib axis, e.g., as output from plt.gca().
    """

    x_limits = ax.get_xlim3d()
    y_limits = ax.get_ylim3d()
    z_limits = ax.get_zlim3d()

    x_range = abs(x_limits[1] - x_limits[0])
    x_middle = np.mean(x_limits)
    y_range = abs(y_limits[1] - y_limits[0])
    y_middle = np.mean(y_limits)
    z_range = abs(z_limits[1] - z_limits[0])
    z_middle = np.mean(z_limits)

    # The plot bounding box is a sphere in the sense of the infinity
    # norm, hence I call half the max range the plot radius.
    plot_radius = 0.5*max([x_range, y_range, z_range])

    ax.set_xlim3d([x_middle - plot_radius, x_middle + plot_radius])
    ax.set_ylim3d([y_middle - plot_radius, y_middle + plot_radius])
    ax.set_zlim3d([z_middle - plot_radius, z_middle + plot_radius])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection="3d")

# Use this for matplotlib prior to 3.3.0 only.
#ax.set_aspect("equal'")
#
# Use this for matplotlib 3.3.0 and later.
# https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/17515
ax.set_box_aspect([1.0, 1.0, 1.0])

X = np.random.rand(100)*10+5
Y = np.random.rand(100)*5+2.5
Z = np.random.rand(100)*50+25

scat = ax.scatter(X, Y, Z)

set_axes_equal(ax)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Be aware that using means as the center point won't work in all cases, you should use midpoints. See my comment on tauran's answer.

Comment: My code above does not take the mean of the data, it takes the mean of the existing plot limits.  My function is thus guaranteed to keep in view any points that were in view according to the plot limits set before it was called.  If the user has already set plot limits too restrictively to see all data points, that is a separate issue.  My function allows more flexibility because you may want to view only a subset of the data.  All I do is expand axis limits so the aspect ratio is 1:1:1.

Comment: Another way to put it: if you take a mean of only 2 points, namely the bounds on a single axis, then that mean IS the midpoint.  So, as far as I can tell, Dalum's function below should be mathematically equivalent to mine and there was nothing to ``fix''.

Comment: Doesn't work in my case,. Obviously [x and z scales are not identical](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnQ8Z.png). I get the same result even if I plot nothing. I suspect this is because [matplotlib adds unequal padding to the subplot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30196503/774575).

Answer (score 69):

**Simple fix!**

I've managed to get this working in version 3.3.1.

It looks like this issue has perhaps been resolved in [PR#17172](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/17515); You can use the `ax.set_box_aspect([1,1,1])` function to ensure the aspect is correct (see the notes for the [set_aspect](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.set_aspect) function). When used in conjunction with the bounding box function(s) provided by @karlo and/or @Matee Ulhaq, the plots now look correct in 3D!

[image: matplotlib 3d plot with equal axes]

**Minimum Working Example**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d
import numpy as np

# Functions from @Mateen Ulhaq and @karlo
def set_axes_equal(ax: plt.Axes):
    """Set 3D plot axes to equal scale.

    Make axes of 3D plot have equal scale so that spheres appear as
    spheres and cubes as cubes.  Required since `ax.axis('equal')`
    and `ax.set_aspect('equal')` don't work on 3D.
    """
    limits = np.array([
        ax.get_xlim3d(),
        ax.get_ylim3d(),
        ax.get_zlim3d(),
    ])
    origin = np.mean(limits, axis=1)
    radius = 0.5 * np.max(np.abs(limits[:, 1] - limits[:, 0]))
    _set_axes_radius(ax, origin, radius)

def _set_axes_radius(ax, origin, radius):
    x, y, z = origin
    ax.set_xlim3d([x - radius, x + radius])
    ax.set_ylim3d([y - radius, y + radius])
    ax.set_zlim3d([z - radius, z + radius])

# Generate and plot a unit sphere
u = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
v = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)
x = np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v)) # np.outer() -> outer vector product
y = np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v))
z = np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(v))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z)

ax.set_box_aspect([1,1,1]) # IMPORTANT - this is the new, key line
# ax.set_proj_type('ortho') # OPTIONAL - default is perspective (shown in image above)
set_axes_equal(ax) # IMPORTANT - this is also required
plt.show()
```

Comment: ax.set_box_aspect([np.ptp(i) for i in data])  # equal aspect ratio

Comment: `AttributeError: 'Axes3DSubplot' object has no attribute 'set_box_aspect'` as of `matplotlib==3.2.2`, but works on later versions including at least `matplotlib==3.6.3`

Answer (score 57):

I simplified Remy F's solution by using the `set_x/y/zlim` [functions](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim).

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.set_aspect('equal')

X = np.random.rand(100)*10+5
Y = np.random.rand(100)*5+2.5
Z = np.random.rand(100)*50+25

scat = ax.scatter(X, Y, Z)

max_range = np.array([X.max()-X.min(), Y.max()-Y.min(), Z.max()-Z.min()]).max() / 2.0

mid_x = (X.max()+X.min()) * 0.5
mid_y = (Y.max()+Y.min()) * 0.5
mid_z = (Z.max()+Z.min()) * 0.5
ax.set_xlim(mid_x - max_range, mid_x + max_range)
ax.set_ylim(mid_y - max_range, mid_y + max_range)
ax.set_zlim(mid_z - max_range, mid_z + max_range)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I like the simplified code.  Just be aware that some (very few) data points may not get plotted.  For example, suppose that X=[0, 0, 0, 100] so that X.mean()=25.  If max_range comes out to be 100 (from X), then you're x-range will be 25 +- 50, so [-25, 75] and you'll miss the X[3] data point.  The idea is very nice though, and easy to modify to make sure you get all the points.

Comment: Beware that using means as the center is not correct. You should use something like `midpoint_x = np.mean([X.max(),X.min()])` and then set the limits to `midpoint_x` +/- `max_range`. Using the mean only works if the mean is located at the midpoint of the dataset, which is not always true. Also, a tip: you can scale max_range to make the graph look nicer if there are points near or on the boundaries.

Comment: After I updated anaconda, ax.set_aspect("equal") reported error:
NotImplementedError: It is not currently possible to manually set the aspect on 3D axes

Comment: Rather than calling `set_aspect('equal')`, use `set_box_aspect([1,1,1])`, as described in my answer below. It's working for me in matplotlib version 3.3.1!

Answer (score 27):

As of matplotlib 3.3.0, [Axes3D.set_box_aspect](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.set_box_aspect) seems to be the recommended approach.

```
import numpy as np

xs, ys, zs = <your data>
ax = <your axes>

# Option 1: aspect ratio is 1:1:1 in data space
ax.set_box_aspect((np.ptp(xs), np.ptp(ys), np.ptp(zs)))

# Option 2: aspect ratio 1:1:1 in view space
ax.set_box_aspect((1, 1, 1))
```

Answer (score 23):

Adapted from @karlo's answer to make things even cleaner:

```
def set_axes_equal(ax: plt.Axes):
    """Set 3D plot axes to equal scale.

    Make axes of 3D plot have equal scale so that spheres appear as
    spheres and cubes as cubes.  Required since `ax.axis('equal')`
    and `ax.set_aspect('equal')` don't work on 3D.
    """
    limits = np.array([
        ax.get_xlim3d(),
        ax.get_ylim3d(),
        ax.get_zlim3d(),
    ])
    origin = np.mean(limits, axis=1)
    radius = 0.5 * np.max(np.abs(limits[:, 1] - limits[:, 0]))
    _set_axes_radius(ax, origin, radius)

def _set_axes_radius(ax, origin, radius):
    x, y, z = origin
    ax.set_xlim3d([x - radius, x + radius])
    ax.set_ylim3d([y - radius, y + radius])
    ax.set_zlim3d([z - radius, z + radius])
```

**Usage:**

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.set_aspect('equal')         # important!

# ...draw here...

set_axes_equal(ax)             # important!
plt.show()
```

---

**EDIT:** This answer does not work on more recent versions of Matplotlib due to the changes merged in [`pull-request #13474`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/13474), which is tracked in [`issue #17172`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/17172) and [`issue #1077`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1077). As a temporary workaround to this, one can remove the newly added lines in [`lib/matplotlib/axes/_base.py`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/13474/commits/29b048f5105b77f4c75178ddd995f74e4379294a#diff-a7f4f21aa80e975d813bc436acb68d8cR1274-R1279):

```
  class _AxesBase(martist.Artist):
      ...

      def set_aspect(self, aspect, adjustable=None, anchor=None, share=False):
          ...

+         if (not cbook._str_equal(aspect, 'auto')) and self.name == '3d':
+             raise NotImplementedError(
+                 'It is not currently possible to manually set the aspect '
+                 'on 3D axes')
```

Comment: Love this, but after I updated anaconda, ax.set_aspect("equal") reported error:
NotImplementedError: It is not currently possible to manually set the aspect on 3D axes

Comment: @Ewan I added some links at the bottom of my answer to help in investigation. It looks as if the MPL folks are breaking workarounds without properly fixing the issue for some reason. ¯\\\_(ツ)\_/¯

Comment: I think I found a workaround (that doesn't require modifying the source code) for the NotImplementedError (full description in my answer below); basically add `ax.set_box_aspect([1,1,1])` before calling `set_axes_equal`

Comment: Just found this post and tried, failed on ax.set_aspect('equal'). Not an issue though if you just remove ax.set_aspect('equal') from your script but keep the two custom functions set_axes_equal and _set_axes_radius...making sure to call them before the plt.show(). Great solution for me! I've been searching for some time over a couple of years, finally. I've always reverted to python's vtk module for 3D plotting, especially when the number of things gets extreme.

Answer (score 9):

As of matplotlib 3.6.0, this feature [has been added](https://matplotlib.org/3.6.0/users/prev_whats_new/whats_new_3.6.0.html#equal-aspect-ratio-for-3d-plots) with the command
`ax.set_aspect('equal')`. Other options are `'equalxy'`, `'equalxz'`, and `'equalyz'`, to set only two directions to equal aspect ratios. This changes the data limits, example below.

In the upcoming 3.7.0, [you will be able](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/23552) to change the plot box aspect ratios rather than the data limits via the command `ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')`. To get the original behavior, use `adjustable='datalim'`.

[image]

Comment: 3.7.0 is now released, so `adjustable='datalim'` and `adjustable='box'` are now both valid options.

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT:** user2525140's code should work perfectly fine, although this answer supposedly attempted to fix a non--existant error. The answer below is just a duplicate (alternative) implementation:

```
def set_aspect_equal_3d(ax):
    """Fix equal aspect bug for 3D plots."""

    xlim = ax.get_xlim3d()
    ylim = ax.get_ylim3d()
    zlim = ax.get_zlim3d()

    from numpy import mean
    xmean = mean(xlim)
    ymean = mean(ylim)
    zmean = mean(zlim)

    plot_radius = max([abs(lim - mean_)
                       for lims, mean_ in ((xlim, xmean),
                                           (ylim, ymean),
                                           (zlim, zmean))
                       for lim in lims])

    ax.set_xlim3d([xmean - plot_radius, xmean + plot_radius])
    ax.set_ylim3d([ymean - plot_radius, ymean + plot_radius])
    ax.set_zlim3d([zmean - plot_radius, zmean + plot_radius])
```

Comment: You still need to do: `ax.set_aspect('equal')` or the tick values may be screwed up. Otherwise good solution. Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I think this feature has been added to matplotlib since these answers have been posted.  In case anyone is still searching a solution this is how I do it:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
    
fig = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(1)*2)
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d', proj_type='ortho')
    
X = np.random.rand(100)
Y = np.random.rand(100)
Z = np.random.rand(100)
    
ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, color='b')
```

The key bit of code is `figsize=plt.figaspect(1)` which sets the aspect ratio of the figure to 1 by 1. The `*2` after `figaspect(1)` scales the figure by a factor of two. You can set this scaling factor to whatever you want.

**NOTE**: This only works for figures with one plot.

[image: Random 3D scatter Plot]

Answer (score 0):

- for the time beeing `ax.set_aspect('equal')` araises an error (version `3.5.1` with Anaconda).
- `ax.set_aspect('auto',adjustable='datalim')` did not give a convincing solution either.
- a lean work-aorund with `ax.set_box_aspect((asx,asy,asz))` and `asx, asy, asz = np.ptp(X), np.ptp(Y), np.ptp(Z)` seems to be feasible (see my code snippet)
- Let's hope that version `3.7` with the features @Scott mentioned will be successful soon.

  ```
  import numpy as np
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

  #---- generate data
  nn = 100
  X = np.random.randn(nn)*20 +  0
  Y = np.random.randn(nn)*50 + 30
  Z = np.random.randn(nn)*10 + -5

  #---- check aspect ratio
  asx, asy, asz = np.ptp(X), np.ptp(Y), np.ptp(Z)

  fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
  ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

  #---- set box aspect ratio
  ax.set_box_aspect((asx,asy,asz))
  scat = ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, c=X+Y+Z, s=500, alpha=0.8)

  ax.set_xlabel('X-axis'); ax.set_ylabel('Y-axis'); ax.set_zlabel('Z-axis')
  plt.show()
  ```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It appears:

```
ax.set_aspect('equal')
```

works, but be careful to execute this instruction only when all plots are done. The code modifies the limits of the plot based on the ranges that have been used, and therefore would not calculate accurate limits if the subplot is not complete.

Documentation: [mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.set_aspect](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.set_aspect.html)

[image]

The three unit vectors in black have an equal length, in spite of the very different ranges for each axis.

**Code used**

It is interesting to look at [the code](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v3.8.0/lib/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py#L278-L361).

- The ranges used by the plots are obtained by calling `get_view_interval()`
- The new aspect is set by calling `set_box_aspect(box_aspect)`

---

```
view_intervals = np.array([self.xaxis.get_view_interval(),
                           self.yaxis.get_view_interval(),
                           self.zaxis.get_view_interval()])
ptp = np.ptp(view_intervals, axis=1)
if self._adjustable == 'datalim':
...
else:  # 'box'
    # Change the box aspect such that the ratio of the length of
    # the unmodified axis to the length of the diagonal
    # perpendicular to it remains unchanged.
    box_aspect = np.array(self._box_aspect)
    box_aspect[ax_indices] = ptp[ax_indices]
    remaining_ax_indices = {0, 1, 2}.difference(ax_indices)
    if remaining_ax_indices:
        remaining = remaining_ax_indices.pop()
        old_diag = np.linalg.norm(self._box_aspect[ax_indices])
        new_diag = np.linalg.norm(box_aspect[ax_indices])
        box_aspect[remaining] *= new_diag / old_diag
    self.set_box_aspect(box_aspect)
```

**Example**

The code corresponding to the figure above.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Convert a point array to arrays of x, y and z coords
def split_xyz(points):
    _p = np.asarray(points)
    return _p[:,0], _p[:,1], _p[:,2]

# Origin
o = np.array([0,0,0])

# Vectors
u = np.array([3,3,1])
v = np.array([0,0.2,1.2])

# Projection of v onto u
n = np.linalg.norm(u)
p = u.dot(v) / n**2 * u

# Projection of v onto plane normal to u
w = v - p

# Figure
kw = dict(figsize=(7,7), layout='constrained')
fig = plt.figure(**kw)
mosaic = [['3d']]
kw = {'3d': dict(projection = '3d')}
axs = fig.subplot_mosaic(mosaic, per_subplot_kw=kw)
ax = axs['3d']

# Plot origin
ax.scatter([0],[0],[0], s=50, c='k')
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')

# Plot unit vectors
units = [(1,0,0), (0,1,0),(0,0,1)]
for _v in units: ax.plot(*split_xyz([o, _v]), c='k')

# Plot vectors
for _v, label in zip([u,v], ['u','v']):
    ax.plot(*split_xyz([o, _v]), label=label, lw=2)

# Plot projections
for _v, label in zip([p,w], ['p','w']):
    ax.plot(*split_xyz([o, _v]), label=label, lw=4, alpha=0.5)

# Plot projection lines
for _v in [p, w]: ax.plot(*split_xyz([v, _v]), c='darkgray', ls='--')

# Add legend
ax.legend()

ax.set_aspect('equal')
```