# Plotting x^2 + y^2 = z^2 = 1 using matplotlib without parametric form

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, sympy

I want to plot the unit sphere x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1  & I am trying to use sympy , numpy , and matplotlib for the same.
Below is a code snippet:

```
x,y = sp.symbols('x y')

def g(x,y):
    return sqrt(1-x**2 - y**2)
xrange2 = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
yrange2 = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
X2, Y2 = np.meshgrid(xrange2, yrange2)
Z2 = g(X2, Y2)
Z2[(1- X2**2 - Y2**2 < 0)] = np.nan
Z2[(1- X2**2 - Y2**2 > 0)] = np.nan
ax.plot_surface(X2, Y2, Z2,cmap='Blues', antialiased=True, edgecolor='black')
```

I don't wish to use parametric equations for the sphere, but rather plot it using x , y and z.
Currently getting below error:
Z contains NaN values. This may result in rendering artifacts.

Comment: I am not sure how this works yet. But two things from your code:
1.) Z2 = g(X2, Y2) is actually not valid for a sphere. Mathematically, both +g(X2,Y2) and -g(X2,Y2) are points on sphere at (X2, Y2). I think that's why people introduce parametric equations. Because a sphere/circle is not really a function in terms of y vs x or z vs (x,y)
2.) you are setting everything except for 0 in your Z2 to nan, that's why you have the NaN value error.
Z2[(1- X2**2 - Y2**2 < 0)] = np.nan
Z2[(1- X2**2 - Y2**2 > 0)] = np.nan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the question it is very unclear which version of `sqrt` is used. Sympy's `sqrt` certainly won't work. `math.sqrt` doesn't work on arrays. Only `np.sqrt` can work. But then, function `g` needs to be numpy vectorized.

`np.sqrt` works on arrays, and gives `NaN` when operated on negative numbers.

`ax.plot_surface` doesn't want to draw colormapped faces when some of the Z values are NaN, it only draws plain colors in that case. Note that antialiasing doesn't work for plotting faces, only for edges.

To draw a complete sphere, both `Z2` and `-Z2` need to be drawn.

Due to the `NaN`s and an equation that doesn't define evenly distributed points, some artifacts will be present. Also, the surfaces will not completely fill up. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51645694/how-to-plot-a-perfectly-smooth-sphere-in-python-using-matplotlib) to draw a sphere via an angular representation.

```py
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

@np.vectorize
def g(x,y):
    return np.sqrt(1-x**2 - y**2)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

xrange2 = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
yrange2 = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
X2, Y2 = np.meshgrid(xrange2, yrange2)
Z2 = g(X2, Y2)
ax.plot_surface(X2, Y2, -Z2, color='lightblue', antialiased=True, edgecolor='black')
ax.plot_surface(X2, Y2, Z2, color='lightblue', antialiased=True, edgecolor='black')

plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

PS: Note that you are not really using sympy in the code (def `g(x,y)` uses its own version of standard Python variables x and y). Also, mixing numpy and sympy doesn't work. [This related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60332066/plot-a-perfect-sphere-with-equal-axes-by-parametric-plot-in-sympy) handles plotting a surface as parametric surface via sympy. Note that these parametric surfaces only work for 2 variables, in this case x, y and z are defined in function of phi and theta. As far as I am aware, plotting a general 3D equation doesn't work with sympy at the moment.

Comment: Thanks JohanC , I think matplotlib has limitations when drawing implicit surfaces. Even when I draw the parametric form , it looks like an ellipse. I tried to update to latest version and also tried to use the command on equal spacing , but that didn't work

Comment: Well, yes, for 3D there are a lot of limitations. There is only approximate z-ordering and a difficult to control perspective transformation.