# matplotlib 3D plot axes aspect ratio

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting some 3D data and the plot always creates a 3D cube. It makes sense but I'd like to extend one axis to be longer (aspect ratio) than the others. This will create a 3D rectangle rather than a 3D cube.

For example, the plot below is fully functional - how can I make the y-axis longer relative to the others (visually)?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


N = 1000

bm = pd.DataFrame(
    index=pd.bdate_range(start='2012-01-01', periods=N, freq='B'), 
    data={x: np.random.randn(N) for x in range(1, 11)}
)

# Simulate some zeros
bm = pd.DataFrame(index=bm.index, columns=bm.columns, data=np.where(np.abs(bm.values) < 0.02, 0, bm.values))

# Set zeros to Nan so that I don't plot them
bm = bm.replace({0: np.nan})

# unstack dataframe
flat_bm = bm.reset_index(drop=True).unstack()  # DROP DATES AND REPLACE WITH INT
x = flat_bm.index.get_level_values(0)
y = flat_bm.index.get_level_values(1)
z = flat_bm.values


# Set up plot
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (15,10))
ax = plt.axes(projection ='3d')

# plotting
ax.scatter(x, y, z, '.', c=flat_bm.values, cmap='Reds')
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my problem is:

```
ax.set_box_aspect((1,2,1))
```

see: https://matplotlib.org/3.7.3/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.set_box_aspect.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.set_box_aspect

Related: [How to set the 'equal' aspect ratio for all axes (x, y, z)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685386/how-to-set-the-equal-aspect-ratio-for-all-axes-x-y-z)