# How do I crop an Axes3D plot with square aspect ratio?

Tags: python, matplotlib, aspect-ratio, mplot3d

Here's a barebones example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
f = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1, projection='3d')
t = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 2, projection='3d')

# axes
for d in {f, t}:
    d.plot([-1, 1], [0, 0], [0, 0], color='k', alpha=0.8, lw=2)
    d.plot([0, 0], [-1, 1], [0, 0], color='k', alpha=0.8, lw=2)
    d.plot([0, 0], [0, 0], [-1, 1], color='k', alpha=0.8, lw=2)

f.dist = t.dist = 5.2   # 10 is default

plt.tight_layout()
f.set_aspect('equal')
t.set_aspect('equal')

r = 6
f.set_xlim3d([-r, r])
f.set_ylim3d([-r, r])
f.set_zlim3d([-r, r])

t.set_xlim3d([-r, r])
t.set_ylim3d([-r, r])
t.set_zlim3d([-r, r])

f.set_axis_off()
t.set_axis_off()

plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

This is what I get:

[image: square viewports]

This is what I want:

[image: rectangular viewports]

In other words, I want the plots themselves to have a square aspect ratio, not all stretched out like this:

[image: stretched out]

and I got that part working thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/31364297/125507

but I want the windows looking into those plots to be rectangular, with the top and bottom cropped out (since there will just be white space on top and bottom and I'm generating multiple animated GIFs so I can't easily post-process it to the shape I want).

Basically I am making this animation, and I want the same thing but without all the whitespace:

> [image: animation]

Comment: I am not usre your example is representative enough, have you tried `fig.subplots_adjust(top = 1, bottom = 0, right = 1, left = 0, 
            hspace = 0, wspace = 0)`?

Comment: Apart from that, you need to tighten your `r`

Comment: @rll Yeah I shortened one axis from what I actually want, to illustrate them all being the same length

Comment: I added a bounty to this and still don't have an answer.  Do I need to make something more clear?

Comment: Are the answers in [Setting aspect ratio of 3D plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326371/setting-aspect-ratio-of-3d-plot) and [matplotlib (mplot3d) - how to increase the size of an axis (stretch) in a 3D Plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30223161/matplotlib-mplot3d-how-to-increase-the-size-of-an-axis-stretch-in-a-3d-plo) not working? What's different here?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Which part of those fixes my problem? I don't want to change the aspect ratio, I want to change the amount of whitespace around the plots

Comment: The only problem with the third picture you show is the aspect, right? The links would provide ways to set the aspect; so it seems they would suit your needs.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest The third picture is what I **don't** want, and is what those answers provide.

Answer (score 6):

In order to follow up on my comments and show examples by settting a smaller `r` and removing subplot margins using `subplots_adjust`:

```
 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
f = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1, projection='3d')
t = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 2, projection='3d')

# axes
for d in {f, t}:
    d.plot([-1, 1], [0, 0], [0, 0], color='k', alpha=0.8, lw=2)
    d.plot([0, 0], [-1, 1], [0, 0], color='k', alpha=0.8, lw=2)
    d.plot([0, 0], [0, 0], [-1, 1], color='k', alpha=0.8, lw=2)

f.dist = t.dist = 5.2   # 10 is default

plt.tight_layout()
f.set_aspect('equal')
t.set_aspect('equal')

r = 1
f.set_xlim3d([-r, r])
f.set_ylim3d([-r, r])
f.set_zlim3d([-r, r])

t.set_xlim3d([-r, r])
t.set_ylim3d([-r, r])
t.set_zlim3d([-r, r])

f.set_axis_off()
t.set_axis_off()

fig.subplots_adjust(top = 1, bottom = 0, right = 1, left = 0, 
            hspace = 0, wspace = 0)

plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

This will give tighter subplots, as the defaults for [SubplotParams](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.SubplotParams) are as follows:

> left : 0.125
>
> right : 0.9
>
> bottom : 0.1
>
> top : 0.9
>
> wspace : 0.2
>
> hspace : 0.2

not sure it is this the OP is looking for though...

[image]

Comment: each plot is still square, though, I want to make them rectangles while still having equal axes

Answer (score 0):

Related Matplotlib issue:

- [Too much white space around graphs in 3d projection
  #19519](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/19519)

One of the devs [says](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/19519#issuecomment-780002963):

> Yes, the original Axes3D didn't work within the subplot() framework. And subplots leave extra room for the static axes labels, meanwhile, Axes3D needed to account for extra space for its axes labels within the axes plotting area. Originally, this was fine because you didn't make Axes3D objects using subplots, so you didn't get allocated extra margins for axes labels. When it became possible to specify `projection='3d'` to a subplot call, this had the inadvertent effect of getting extra margin space that wasn't really needed.
>
> I never did figure out a good solution for this that wouldn't act counter-intuitively. Perhaps Axes3D needs to be reworked such that it can interpret and express the margin parameters itself rather than letting it be handled by 2D-based assumptions?

Answer (score -1):

Since you want rectangular plot, you cannot use `set_aspect('equal')`, instead you have to adjust the limits of your plots to account for the difference in aspect ratios.

In the attempt below, I've used the `bbox` of the axis to get the `height` and `width` of the axes and used the aspect ratio to rescale `X` and `Y` axes. (I assumed both plots have the same dimension, but uou could also have plots with different dimensions, you'll just have to adjust the axes limits independently for each one).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
f = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1, projection='3d')
t = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 2, projection='3d')

# axes
for d in {f, t}:
    d.plot([-1, 1], [0, 0], [0, 0], color='k', alpha=0.8, lw=2)
    d.plot([0, 0], [-1, 1], [0, 0], color='k', alpha=0.8, lw=2)
    d.plot([0, 0], [0, 0], [-1, 1], color='k', alpha=0.8, lw=2)

f.dist = t.dist = 5.2   # 10 is default

plt.tight_layout()
# Cannot use 'equal' aspect for a rectangular plot
# f.set_aspect('equal')
# t.set_aspect('equal')

# get the dimensions of the axes from its bbox
f_bbox = f.get_position()
f_height = f_bbox.height
f_width = f_bbox.width


r = 6
f.set_xlim3d([-1 * f_width/f_height * r, f_width/f_height * r])
f.set_ylim3d([-1 * f_width/f_height * r, f_width/f_height * r])
f.set_zlim3d([-r, r])

t.set_xlim3d([-1 * f_width/f_height * r, f_width/f_height * r])
t.set_ylim3d([-1 * f_width/f_height * r, f_width/f_height * r])
t.set_zlim3d([-r, r])

f.set_axis_off()
t.set_axis_off()

plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Note: In this picture, I've added a background color to highlight the rectangular shape of the plots

Comment: they don't maintain aspect ratio when rotated though.  the viewport needs to be cropped into a rectangle, not shrunk into one