# A propper way to get correct aspect-ratio in 3D plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, aspect-ratio, mplot3d

First of all full disclaimer, I am new to python and my question may be silly, but as far as my research has taught me it seems there is no supported way in `matplotlib` to do what I want.

I have to plot trajectories of the Three Body Problem and I am trying to do it with python to be less dependent of `Matlab` (which is what they teach at my University). In these plots appear both Earth and Moon, and it is important for me that they look spherical. The next code gives a basic example of the kind of thing that I have to plot:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D, proj3d # Needed to 3Dplots
plt.close('all') # Close plots of previous scripts

#Data
Er = 0.0166         # Earth radius
Mr = 0.0045         # Moon radius
mu = 0.01215        # Mass parameter
#
def plotCC(ax,rad,pos): # Plot celestial bodies
     u = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 53)
     v = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 53)
     x = pos +  rad * np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v))
     y = rad * np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v))
     z = rad * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(v))
     ax.plot_surface(x, y, z)

# Dummy Halo orbit    
u   = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 30)
xh  = (1-mu)*np.ones(len(u))
yh  = 20*Mr*np.sin(u)
zh  = 0.12 + 30*Mr*np.cos(u)

# Dummy trajectory
xt  = np.linspace(1-mu,-mu,20)
yt  = (xt-(1-mu))*(xt+mu)*-1.2
zt  = (xt-(1-mu))*(xt+mu)*-0.8
```

Using that I can plot all I need with:

```py
# Plots
fig     = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
ax      = fig.gca(projection='3d',proj_type = 'ortho')
ax.plot(xh,yh,zh, lw=1.2)   # Plot Halo orbit
ax.plot(xt,yt,zt, lw=1.2)   # Plot trajectory
plotCC(ax,Mr,1-mu)          # Plot Moon
plotCC(ax,Er,-mu)           # Plot Earth
```

Which gives as a result this:

[Plot without any changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnRHj.png)

It is far of what I need, as none of the celestial bodies are represented as spheres. I thought that the aspect-ratio could be configured to match that of the represented data, but none of the supported methods that I found seem to do just that. This methods are: `ax.axis('equal')`, `ax.set_aspect('equal')`, `ax.axis('scaled')`, `ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')`, `ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='datalim')`. None of these do the job.

The first closest thing that I found is this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31364297/11095347), which basically creates a box so that all axis measure the same. This does the trick, but in my case one of the dimensions is much bigger than the others, and this results in a lot of wasted space:

[Plot with the solution that creates a box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1N1ht.png)

Finally, the best thing that I could find is the solution in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10328142/11095347), which requires to modify the file `axes.py` so that `get_proj()` accepts an aspect ratio that you give to it with:

```py
ay = (ax.get_ylim3d()[1]-ax.get_ylim3d()[0])/(ax.get_xlim3d()[1]-ax.get_xlim3d()[0])
az = (ax.get_zlim3d()[1]-ax.get_zlim3d()[0])/(ax.get_xlim3d()[1]-ax.get_xlim3d()[0])
ax.pbaspect = list(1.8*np.array([1,ay,az]))
```

The result is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2cO6.png). If you look closely the plot isn't centered, and depending in the orientation not all the data is inside the drawing area. For now I will use this last method, but after all the research that I have done I still can't believe that something like this isn't supported as it should by a plotting tool (which is fantastic in everything else as far as I know), and thus my question: Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Short answer: No you are not missing anything. The `pbaspect` hasn't been adopted into matplotlib because it can cause some problems  (one of which you found here I think). Did you try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30223161/matplotlib-mplot3d-how-to-increase-the-size-of-an-axis-stretch-in-a-3d-plo)?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I saw that post but though that the answer was basically doing the same that the `bpaspect` method (or so I though). I have just tried it and it gives a good result, with the difference being that you can't change the size of the plot (as I did in `ax.pbaspect = list(1.8*np.array([1,ay,az]))`, so nothing very promising...

Comment: The size should be determined by the size of the axes; so it's independent of the aspect. It shouldn't be a criterion by which to evaluate the solutions.